# dynamic query with dynamic subquery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying (and failing) to create a dynamic query with a subquery.
I have a table of questions where the possible answers to each question need to be created dynamically from one or several other tables. I have a varchar field in the questions table that I want to use dynamically to query the possible answers. Example:

Questions Table:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
id | question          | answer_query
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | Can this be done? | SELECT field1 + ' ' + field2 answers FROM table1 a JOIN table2 b ON b.field1 = a.field2 WHERE b.id = '@id'
```

Then I want a stored proc that creates a dynamic query like this:

```
DECLARE @id int
SET @id.......
DECLARE @sql_query varchar(3000);
SET @sql_query = 
    'SELECT q.id, q.question, (REPLACE(q.answer_query, ''@id'', @id))
    FROM Questions q
    JOIN Other Table ON ....
    WHERE .....';

EXECUTE(@sql_query);
```

Apologies for the poor formatting!

Is what I am trying to do possible?

---

Comment: my first reaction is: don't do that. If you're going to do something like that anyway, start here: [The curse and blessings of dynamic SQL - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Comment: As a general principle, if you NEED to use dynamic SQL, do not do it like you're doing it here or like McNets suggested in his answer (using `EXEC()`, even though McNets suggested an incorrect answer for other reasons). Use `EXEC sp_executesql` instead. It allows for properly parameterising your queries. Here is an article describing why it's a [bad habit](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp_executesql).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @id int
SET @id.......
DECLARE @sql_query varchar(3000);
SET @sql_query = 
    'SELECT q.id, q.question, ' 
    + (REPLACE(q.answer_query, '@id', @id))
    + ' FROM Questions q
    JOIN Other Table ON ....
    WHERE .....';

EXECUTE(@sql_query);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
SET @sql_query = (SELECT REPLACE(q.answer_query, '@id', @id)
  FROM Questions q
  JOIN Other Table ON ....
  WHERE .....)
```

or

```
SELECT @sql_query = REPLACE(q.answer_query, '@id', @id)
FROM Questions q
JOIN Other Table ON ....
WHERE .....)
```

However this seems like a really bad idea for many reasons.  Is there any other way to solve this problem.

For example -- instead of having the select statement in the table, reverence a view name.  This solves many problems, the compiler can optimize you are not open to sql injection -- so much good.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to understand the query properly. Assumes that you want to replace the string *'@id'* from the **answer_query** with the values in the variable *@id*.

If so, please try the below query:

```
DECLARE @id int
SET @id=.....
DECLARE @sql_query varchar(3000);
SET @sql_query = 
    'SELECT q.id, q.question, (REPLACE(q.answer_query, ''@id'', '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@id)+'))
    FROM Questions q
    JOIN Other Table ON ....
    WHERE .....';
EXECUTE(@sql_query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your comments. I have come up with the following solution, which is not as generic as I would like.

[Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhfQy.png)

Stored Proc:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spQuestionsByTypeAndOther]
    @type_id uniqueidentifier,
    @other_param_id uniqueidentifier
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT q.id, q.question, q.required, dbo.fnGetAnswers(q.id, @other_param_id)
    FROM Questions q
    JOIN QuestionsToTypes t on t.question_id = q.id
    WHERE t.type_id = @type_id
END
```

And a function (fnGetAnswers) which uses a case statement to return the answers based on the question id and one other parameter. Each case performs a different query against other tables in the database and flattens/concatenates the results into a csv string.